# .netcore 3.1 load multiple SO files for one function

Tags: .net-core

I have loaded a function from my C++ library but it relies on functions in libnl-3 and libnl-route-3. Is there a way to load the libnl shared objects and my library

I load my library like this

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.so")]
public static extern void* myFunction();
```

but I cannot find a way to load another shared library

```
[DllImport("libnl-3")]
[DllImport("MyLibrary.so")]
public static extern void* myFunction();
```

does not work

If when I run the application I put LD_PRELOAD="libnl-3.so libnl-route-3.so" before it in the terminal the application works but I dont want to have to use LD_PRELOAD every time.

Comment: a few things to check.... are the libraries in question in the same folder as the other library? what are the compilation properties in the Properties window for the main library and also for the dependent libraries...

Comment: The libraries are all stored in /usr/lib. I dont know what the properties are for nl-3 and nl-route-3 these were already compiled when I downloaded them. I compiled my library using cmake with `add_library(MyLibrary SHARED "files.c ...")`

Comment: Yeah the problem is when .net tries to execute a library it needs to know where all the dependencies are... so when you compile YOUR executable... this one has to have references to all the libraries that are going to be used... and then depending on many factors you might have to set those dependencies to "Copy Local" for example.  So once again you need to post pictures of your Properties in visual studio for each of the references in your project.

Comment: I am not using visual studio so can't show this. I have the C# part setup in intellij Rider and the C++ part in intellij CLion. All of this is on linux.

Comment: Still you need to somehow specify a way for your executable to find ALL references needed.  As this is not a feature of "visua studio" but rather of .NET.... You will not be able to skip loading the dependencies one way or another. You say you do not want to use LD_PRELOAD... well you will have to load them some how.

Comment: I dont want to use LD_PRELOAD because it seems clumsy to have to do this everytime. Is there some .net I can write to do this at run time or something I can add to my c++ library to load the dependency when it needs it?

Comment: Alternatively is there a way I should be compiling my library so that it knows where to find the nl-3 library when it is required?

Comment: I would do a search in google for "dynamic assembly loading" and "assembly resolution" in .NET