# How to include C system reference libraries when invoking through a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, debian, shared-libraries

I've got a C-coded shared library (libXXX.so) that I'm trying to wrap within a C# application. So far it is mostly working using an interface similar to the following. Essentially I hold onto a pointer to a C-created struct and use the C-interface functions to analyze/manipulate it.

There are other concerns about handling unmanaged memory - but I feel those are mostly addressed with the destructor (and alternatively IDisposable())

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CS_XXX {
    public CS_XXX(IntPtr p) {
        ptr = p;
    }

    ~CS_XXX() {
        [DllImport("XXX")]
        static extern void XXX_cleanup(IntPtr s);
        XXX_cleanup(ptr);
        ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public int size() {
        [DllImport("XXX")]
        static extern int get_XXX_size(IntPtr s);
        return get_XXX_size(s);
    }

    IntPtr p;
}
```

My problem is that my C-library `libXXX.so` depends on `zlib`. In any other C or C++ compiled application I would also link against `zlib` and it would take in what was needed. But when calling my library from C# I'm not sure how to tell `dotnet` to also include `zlib` (ie. `libz.so.1`).

In this example I am depending on `crc32`. Note: I realize there are other ways of achieving crc32 in .NET - I've only just simplified this example to one simple dependency, there are others.

```
void get_XXX_size(my_struct_t *s) {
    ...
    int v = crc32(0, data, size);
    ...
}
```

I am using `dotnet` on Debian10. I have no current need to port to any other platform as this time.

I have tried adding it to my .csproj file as a reference

```
  <ItemGroup>
      .....
      <Reference Include="z">
          <HintPath>/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1</HintPath>
      </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

or

```
  <ItemGroup>
      .....
      <Reference Include="libz.so">
          <HintPath>/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1</HintPath>
      </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

But it was unsuccessful

`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. [<path>/<project>.csproj]`

**Update:**

I did find a related question --- [.netcore 3.1 load multiple SO files for one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688559/netcore-3-1-load-multiple-so-files-for-one-function) . In that it shows me I can use LD_PRELOAD which works, and does get me moving again. Much like the other question I'd prefer not to need it, but I didn't get very far with the alternatives answered there.

Comment: I did briefly contemplate merging all shared libraries I needed into one - but a quick google search confirmed what I suspected, it's a bad idea no matter what your purpose is.

Comment: I did find a related question --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688559/netcore-3-1-load-multiple-so-files-for-one-function . In that it shows me I can use LD_PRELOAD which works, and does get me moving again. Much like the other question I'd prefer not to need it, but I didn't get very far with the alternatives answered there.